# Simple logical error I'm sure, output is only 0 for my math formula

Tags: function, math, printf, pow

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#define NAME_LENGTH 10
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
double myFunc(double x)
{
  double  y = (pow(x, 3)) - (3 * (pow(x,2))) + 2;
  return y;
}

int main()
{
   double y = 3;
   myFunc(y);
   printf("%d \n", y);
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

To me this should be a very very simple formula. I'm not asking it to jump through many hoops, but it only outputs "0" no matter what value for "y" I give.

I am using Visual Studio 2013. 
I hovered my mouse over "y" and it said "y" equaled "2.0000" in the function, which is the correct output for this particular value of "y."

Comment: Try using the %F format specifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the myFunc return value to y: y = MyFunc(y); And use the format %lf instead of %d.